# Почему могли измениться структурированные данные на 0?

Tags: seo, индексация, schema.org, google-search-console

Есть сайт для гостиницы. Сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой: по какой-то причине в google search console в разделе структурированные данные, в пункте элементы теперь написано 0, хотя было 1. Скрин прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня также смущает дата (19). Почему зависло на 19?

По поводу правок на сайте. Последняя правка была произведена 15 числа. И то, как правка, тупо добавили картинки на сайт и блок с отзывами. Структурированные данные не меняли.

[Ссылка на проверку структурированных данных](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https://%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84)

С чем это может быть связано, и чем мне это может грозить?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации **[Schema "Разметка для отелей"](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html)**: 
При моделировании информации, связанной с гостиницей, в веб-контенте с schema.org существует три основных объекта:

- **[Жильё как бизнес](http://schema.org/LodgingBusiness)** - по существу это место и местный бизнес, в котором размещается фактические единицы, например, гостиничные
  номера.
- **[Жильё как физические места для размещения и проживания людей](http://schema.org/Accommodation)**,например , гостиничные номера, люксы, апартаменты, кемпинги, и т.д.). Это объекты, предлагаемые для аренды
- **[Коммерческие предложения](http://schema.org/Offer)** для аренды гостиничных номеров за определённую сумму денег. 
  Чтобы использовать указанные свойства в качестве предмета предложения, вы должны использовать технику вложения для определения ваших экземпляров как подкласса **Accomodation**. Отношения между Accommodation и LodgingBusiness, например, как связь определённого гостиничного номера с отелем, надо предоставлять через **[containedInPlace](http://schema.org/containedInPlace)** или же как связь отеля с конкретным гостиничным номером - через **[containsPlace](http://schema.org/containsPlace)**.

Взаимосвязь между коммерческим предложением и гостиничным номером может быть представлена с использованием элемента makesOffer (свойство LodgingBusiness) и расширенным описанием коммерческого предложения с использованием вложения Offer. Смотрите **[графическую схему](http://schema.org/docs/schema_hotels_1.png)** подобной разметки.

Всего этого нет в структурированной разметке вашего веб-сайта.

Также, в указанной вами разметке, имеется элемент **[priceRange](http://schema.org/priceRange)** с содержанием = 1200. Этот элемент указывает диапазон цен коммерческого предложения, т.е. это минимальная и максимальная цена - это две цифры.

Вы используете структурированную разметку как микродата. Эта разметка является частью исходного кода веб-страницы. Но исходный код указанной веб-страницы имеет **[множество ошибок, в том числе и Fatal Error](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showoutline=yes&useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&acceptlanguage=&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fxn--80adce4aloy.xn--p1ai%2F)**, на котором бот останавливается. Эти ошибки мешают поисковым ботам правильно понимать структуру веб-страницы и структурированной разметки.

Почему именно 19 октября? Возможно было очередное обновление поискового алгоритма Гугл, или же они устали ожидать исправлений существующих ошибок.